# How to use for-each in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML which has one set of education brackets.
I use xml-stylesheet which contains related code:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="CV/education">
  <xsl:value-of select="CV/education/college"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="CV/education/fieldOfStudy"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="CV/education/studyStartDate"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="CV/education/studyEndDate"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

This however does not seem to display related values.
I have put

```
      <xsl:value-of select="CV/education/college"/>
```

after for-each bracket and it seems to work.
Can you please let me know what is not correct in used for-each?

Comment: Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) @zx485's fine answer (+1) to your question and consider accepting some of the answers you've received to your past questions on this site.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ignoring the current node in your expressions: `<xsl:for-each select="CV/education">` sets the current node to `CV/education`, so you don't have to repeat that path in your `xsl:value-of` expressions. Relative paths are evaluated relative to the current node.

Simplify your code to

```
<xsl:for-each select="CV/education">
  <xsl:value-of select="college"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="fieldOfStudy"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="studyStartDate"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="studyEndDate"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and it should work as desired.